# C++ stack implementation pop function not working

Tags: c++, stack

I'm implementing a stack with a linked list for review.  My pop function isn't working correctly.  I created a test with the nodes in main doing the exact same thing my linkedList function is doing but I'm getting a segmentation fault ever time time.  Here is the code.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Node{
  int data;
  Node* next;
};

class Stack{
  private:
    Node head;
    int size;
  public:
    Stack();
    ~Stack();
    int getSize();
    void push(int val);
    int pop();
    void printStack();
};

Stack::Stack(){
  head.data = 0;
  head.next = NULL;
}

Stack::~Stack(){
}

int Stack::getSize(){
  return size;
}

void Stack::push(int val){
  Node newNode;
  newNode.data = val;
  if(size == 0) newNode.next = NULL;
  else newNode.next = head.next;
  head.next = &newNode;
  size++;
}

int Stack::pop(){
  int returnVal = head.next->data;
  head.next = head.next->next;
  return returnVal;
}
}


int main(){
  Stack s;
  s.push(8);
  s.push(30);
  s.push(40);
  int value = s.pop();
  int value2 = s.pop(); //segmentation fault
  std::cout<<value<<"\n"<<value2<<"\n"; 


/* This works correctly
  Node head;
  head.data = 0;
  head.next = NULL;
  Node n1;
  n1.data = 5;
  n1.next = NULL;
  head.next = &n1;
  Node n2;
  n2.data = 8;
  n2.next = head.next;
  head.next = &n2;
  Node n3;
  n3.data = 30;
  n3.next = head.next;
  head.next = &n3;

  int value = head.next->data;
  std::cout << value << "\n";
  head.next = head.next->next;
  value = head.next->data;
  std::cout << value << "\n";
*/
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the segmentation fault occurs at the `cout` line and not when calling `pop()` ?

Comment: I'm sorry.  Should've been more specific.  It definitly happens at the SECOND call to pop()

Comment: As well as the actual answers, shouldn't `pop` adjust `size`?

Comment: Need to make new Node

Comment: Once you figure out how to make your manual `Stack` implementation work correctly, you should then update it to use the standard [`std::list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) class instead of a manual list, and then when you have that working correctly, chuck it all out and just use the standard C++ [`std::stack`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack) class instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is how you create the Node. In your case you create a local variable, which only exists within the scope of the function push(). You could use something like this.

```
void Stack::push(int val){
  Node* newNode = new Node;
  newNode->data = val;
  /* ... */ 
}
```

Edit: added a version of the stack (by no means complete)

```
#include <iostream>

struct Node{
  int data;
  Node* next;
};

class Stack {
  private:
    Node* head;
    int size;

  public:
    Stack();
    ~Stack();
    int getSize();
    void push(int val);
    int pop();
    void printStack();
};

Stack::Stack() : head(0), size(0)
{
}

Stack::~Stack(){
}

int Stack::getSize(){
  return size;
}

void Stack::push(int val){
  Node* newNode = new Node;
  newNode->data = val;
  newNode->next = head;

  head = newNode;
  size++;
}

int Stack::pop(){
    if(head != 0)
    {
        int val = head->data;

        Node* tmp = head;
        head = head->next;

        tmp->next = NULL;
        delete tmp;

        size--;

        return val;
    }
    else
    {
        return -1; // what happens if stack is empty ?      
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, will mark you as solution since you provided code to correct issue.

Comment: I think there are other problems with the logic of `push()` and `pop()`.

Comment: The `~Stack()` destructor needs to walk the list deleting any nodes that have not been popped yet, otherwise they will be leaked.  You should also implement the [Rule of three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)) properly by adding a copy constructor and copy assignment operator

Comment: I totally agree, but this is getting out of hands now. Just use std::stack if you want to do something real.

Answer (score 2):

```
void Stack::push(int val){
  Node newNode;
```

`newNode` is declared to be a local object in automatic scope of the `push()` function.

Which means that when `push()` returns, this object is going to get automatically destroyed. That's what "automatic scope" means.

The code in `push()` attempts to insert this object into your stack, and assumes that this object will exist after `push()` returns. This, of course, isn't true, and this ends up corrupting memory, resulting in undefined behavior.

This is not how object lifetime and scope works, fundamentally, in C++.

Answer (score 1):

I think both your `push()` and `pop()` methods have problems.  You can try using these versions:

```
// create new node, point it to current head, and then assign it as new head
void Stack::push(int val){
    Node* newNode = new Node;
    newNode->data = val;
    newNode->next = head;             // OK even if head == NULL
    head = newNode;
    size++;
}

// retrieve value from head (if it exists), pop the head and return the value
int Stack::pop(){
    if (head == NULL) return -1;     // -1 indicates empty stack
    int returnVal = head->data;      // get popped value
    Node* temp = &head;
    head = head->next;               // pop the top of the stack
    delete temp;
    size--;
    return returnVal;
}
```

Comment: What is "head"? Is that the same thing as top?

Answer (score 0):

There's a problem in your code for `push`, actually:

```
void Stack::push(int val){
  Node newNode;
  newNode.data = val;
  if(size == 0) newNode.next = NULL;
  else newNode.next = head.next;
  head.next = &newNode;
  size++;
}
```

When you write

```
Node newNode;
```

you're declaring the `Node` object with *automatic storage duration* (you sometimes hear this called "on the stack"). This `Node` only exists as long as the `push` function is running, and as soon as the function returns the node ceases to exist. Trying to use that node later results in undefined behavior, which in practice could be anything from an outright crash to reading back garbage data.

To address this issue, you'll need to use dynamic allocation. Create the node using `new Node` and store a pointer to it. Objects created this way live until something explicitly destroys them, which means that they'll live after the `push` call finishes. You'll then need to adjust `pop` to deallocate the memory.